# Singapore onward travel requirement - bus ticket enough?

Tags: singapore, malaysia, lufthansa, proof-of-onward-travel

I am going to travel to Singapore from Budapest next month. The carrier is Lufthansa, with a layover in Munich. I have a hungarian passport (EU member), and as I intend to stay for many months in South East Asia travelling around, I have not booked a return flight. I'd like to emphasize that I do not intend to overstay my tourist visa anywhere, everything is legal and I have the monetary means to support my travels.

I have booked a bus ticket from Singapore to Johor Bahru, and I have multiple hotel reservations in succession in Malaysia. Will these statisfy the onward travel proof requirements? What can I expect, how should I go about explaining things if an airline person or immigration official questions me about my travels? Is showing the booking.com application on my phone for the reservations enough or I need to print things? Should I book a fake flight ticket from SG just to be sure?

Comment: *I need to print things* Yes! Always bring printouts. Not any more "secure" - a printout can be faked as easily (possibly easier) as a phone image. But phones can break in 1,000 ways - dropped, battery dead, cellular service problem, etc.

Comment: Thank you, you are right, I'm gonna print out the most important stuff just in case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Immigration and Customs Authority](https://www.ica.gov.sg/enter-transit-depart/entering-singapore):

> Short-Term travellers should have sufficient cash and **proof of onward
> travel (tickets, visas)**, and ensure that you do not stay beyond your
> visit pass validity.

That's it.  The requirement is to have a ticket of any kind, not specifically a plane ticket, so yes, **your bus ticket will be fine**.

FWIW, in my experience you're very unlikely to get asked anything on the Singapore side, but if you have a one-way ticket, you may get asked at the airport when checking in.

Comment: Not Singapore so I won't answer, but on a 26-leg trip with many arrivals requiring "proof of onward travel" the most popular proof was the top sheet in my folder of printed confirmations - a spreadsheet I put together myself showing the date time flight # etc of each leg. People would look on there and see I had written down a plausible onward travel and never bother asking me to prove I had actually booked that. Not saying to try this (I had always booked the other flights) just saying they generally don't demand "proof" per se as much as "show me something".

Comment: thank you, reassuring!

@KateGregory thank you, I have a rough itinerary, I might print that out too (also as a slight off topic: as a C++ programmer it is very strange but wholesome to have you reply to my question :))